# Modular arithmetics

Tags: modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I am having a question specific for this video on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3QnD2c4Xovk They seem to explain that shared encryption concept pretty well, but I seem to get some incorrect result which confuse me a little. The problem is that my calculations and their seem to produce different results.

**In the screenshot above in a comment on youtube, they state that**: ([http://i.imgur.com/3d2Evhd.jpg](https://i.imgur.com/3d2Evhd.jpg)
)

- Alice: $16^{54}\pmod{17}\equiv1$
- Bob: $15^{24}\pmod{17}\equiv1$

**Out of my calculations appears**: (ttp://i.imgur.com/HSqk1mQ.jpg)

- Alice: $16^{54}\pmod{17}\equiv1$
- Bob: $15^{24}\pmod{17}\equiv12$

Comment: Please incorporate the equations into your question instead of asking people to click through.  A guide to formatting can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Hi, welcome to maths stackexchange. Firstly, the last link is broken, you are missing an "h". Secondly, could you be more specific about your problem, and include some details of what the links contain. That way other people can understand the question more easily, especially if/when the links die.

Comment: @Joe Tait Corrected it sir!

Comment: The video's value is the correct one. This isn't actually a math problem, it's simply a programming problem. Assuming you're using Javascript there, the issue is just that JS can't handle such a massive power, so it gives you a floating point approximation (the fact that it got $16^{54}$ right is just a lucky accident, it would seem).

Answer (score 1):

$$16^{54}\equiv_{17}(-1)^{54}=1$$ and $$15^{24}\equiv_{17}(-2)^{24}\equiv_{17}16^6\equiv_{17}(-1)^6=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is correct. I believe javascript had a number overflow, because its limit is $2^{53}$.

$$15^{24}\pmod{17} = 15^{3^8}  \pmod{17} = ((3375^2)^2)^2 \pmod{17}$$

$$= ((9^2)^2)^2 \pmod{17} = (13^2)^2 \mod{17} = 16^2 \pmod{17} = 1$$